# When PPD files are used?

Tags: cups

I have a CUPS server on my Raspberry. The printer is installed along with its filter. When I look on the current driver it says.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ grep -H '^*NickName:' /etc/cups/ppd/*.ppd
/etc/cups/ppd/RICOH_SP_112_DDST.ppd:*NickName: "Ricoh Aficio SP 100, ricoh-sp1xx"
```

The filter is currently disabled.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /usr/lib/cups/filter/ricoh-sp1xx 
#!/bin/bash

/bin/echo "I was here" > /home/pi/aaa.txt
#/usr/bin/python /home/pi/ricoh/ricoh-sp1xx-drv.py $*
```

The printer is also shared through SMB. The strange thing is that I can print from Windows, even with the filter disabled.

Does Windows use its own driver and send the stream directly to the printer, through SMB > CUPS > DirectURI? If so, in which cases the PPD file and filter are used? Can I somehow log the stream that CUPS is receiving from the Windows spooler?